# Webpack ExtractTextPlugin - two output files

Tags: webpack

I need to generate two css files. I tried using

```
new ExtractTextPlugin(['css/style.css','css/head.css'], { allChunks: true })
```

in my config and

```
require('../sass/head.scss');
require('../sass/style.scss');
```

in my main js file.

Unfortunately, it produces an error. What can I do?

Comment: The documentation states that "The ExtractTextPlugin generates an output file per entry" so to achieve what you want you likely have to set up separate entries and then use the `[name]` pattern based on the entry keys to get the filenames you want.

Comment: Was my example helpful?

Answer (score 7):

### How to export multiple CSS files/ fragments using Webpack 2 and ExtractTextPlugin

Basically all I wanted to do was replicating the standard Compass behavior (which would generate a separate CSS file for each SCSS file that wasn't a partial) and adding PostCSS/Autoprefixer.

The answer by Tomasz finally got me on the right track, still there were some errors:

1. webpack complained about a missing output filename, so I added one
2. after that, it complained about 'multiple assets emitting to the same file'

---

So here's my current `webpack.config.js` that will autoprefix and generate two separate CSS files:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

// var ExtractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('dist/[name].css');
var ExtractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('dist/[name]');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        // style: './src/style.scss',
        // extra: './src/extra.scss'
        'style.css': './src/style.scss',
        'extra.css': './src/extra.scss'
    },
    output: {
        // filename: './dist/[name].js'
        filename: './dist/[name]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        "css-loader",
                        "postcss-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        ExtractCSS
    ],
    watch: true
};
```

The key point here was to **remove** the file extensions from `ExtractTextPlugin()` and `output{}` and then **adding** them to `entry{}`, otherwise webpack would generate a JS file for each CSS file, i.e. `dist/style.js` and `dist/extra.js`.

---

My `postcss.config.js`, nothing fancy here:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```

---

And finally `package.json`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^1.3.0",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "webpack": "^2.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

---

Hat tip to manubo [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189#issuecomment-216053379) and [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189#issuecomment-220403391).

---

***Weird glitch:*** when firing up `$ webpack` for the first time, I get what would normally be content of build.js appended to each exported CSS file. Triggering a rebuild by making a modification to any of the SCSS files fixes this. If you know, how to solve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

You need two entry points for that:

```
var styleScss = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    style: 'sass/style.scss',
    head: 'sass/head.scss'
  },

  module: {
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: styleScss.extract(
          'style-loader',
          'css!sass'
        )
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    styleScss
  ]
};
```